# Declare variable as locally as possible

Tags: c, coding-style, linux-kernel

I'm new to Linux kernel development.

One thing that bothers me is a way a variables are declared and initialized.

I'm under impression that code uses variable declaration placement rules for C89/ANSI C (variables are declared at the beginning of block), while  C99 relaxes the rule.

My background is C++ and there many advises from "very clever people" to declare variable as locally as possible - better declare and initialize in the same instruction:

- [Google C++ Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Local_Variables#Local_Variables)
- [C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321113586) - item 18
- A good discussion about it [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321113586).

What is the accepted way to initialize variables in Linux kernel?

Comment: In C you can declare variables only in the beginning of the function. Do you ask about C++? In C there are no variants.

Comment: @Alex Farber: In C89 and before, yes. But as OP said, C99 allows variable definitions after executable statements.

Comment: @Alex: in C (ANSI C / C89; don't know about K&R C / pre-ANSI C) you can declare at the **beginning of a block** -- `int main(void) { /* lots of code */ if (1) { char buf[1000]; } return 0; }`

Comment: Could it be related to performance? When variables are defined at point-of-use, vs. at the top of a function, does the compiler fiddle with the stack pointer as variables come in and out of scope?

Answer (score 8):

I couldn't find a relevant passage in the [Linux kernel coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/process/coding-style.rst). So, follow the convention used in existing code -- declare variables at beginning of block -- or run the risk of your code seeming out-of-place.

Reasons why variables at beginning of block is a Good Thing:

- the target architecture may not have a C99 compiler
- ... *can't think of more reasons*

Comment: +1 The only answer to original question: What is the accepted way to initialize variables in Linux kernel?

Comment: Linux absolutely depends on gcc or a highly gcc-extension-compatible compiler, so your guess at a reason is wrong. It's purely a matter of style.

Comment: yes, it really a matter of style. Linus doesn't like it, that's it.

Answer (score 2):

You should always try to declare variables as locally as possible. If you're using C++ or C99, that would usually be right before the first use.
In older C, doing that doesn't fall under "possible", and there the place to declare those variables would usually be the beginning of the current block.

(I say 'usually' because of some cases with functions and loops where it's better to make them a bit more global...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right, however I'm asking why Linux kernel doesn't follow the rule (at least code I've seen)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I believe C99 wasn't around when they rewrote the kernel in C... So there's a big possibility that they just took that as a code convention kind of thing, and kept on doing that. Or maybe this is for compatability/portability issues, so that linux could be installed on systems that don't know C99.

Comment: these're exactly my guesses too :)

Answer (score 1):

In most normal cases, declare them in the beginning of the function where you are using them. There are exceptions, but they are rare.

if your function is short enough, the deceleration is far away from the first use anyway. If your function is longer then that - it's a good sign your function is too long.

The reason many C++ based coding standards recommend declaring close to use is that C++ data types can be much "fatter" (e.g. thing of class with multiple inheritances etc.) and so take up a lot more space. If you define such an instance at the beginning of a function but use it only much later (and maybe not at all) you are wasting a lot of RAM. This tends to be much less of an issue in C with it's native type only data types.

Comment: You're right why the rule is good for C++. The rule also reduces chances to use uninitialized variable, which is good for C as well for C++.

Comment: Modern compiler issue warnings for use of uninitialized variables, so while this may have been an issue a while back it is not relevant these days, me thinks.

Comment: @gdy I can't agree with you. If we're are talking about platform, which use compiler which doesn't support C99, than I can suppose they may not issue warning in case uninitialized variable is used. But it's only speculation - I don't know it for sure :)

Comment: Sorry to dig this up 10 years later, but that answer is completely wrong. It's recommended in C++ (and any other language, really) to improve code readability and maintainability. That's it. The instructions the compiler emits are most probably the same in both cases if optimization is -O1 or higher. You're not wasting RAM by declaring them at the beginning if your compiler isn't complete garbage. It's all about good code.

Answer (score 1):

There is an oblique reference in the  [Coding Style](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle) document. It says:

> Another measure of the function is the number of local variables.  They
>   shouldn't exceed 5-10, or you're doing something wrong.  Re-think the
>   function, and split it into smaller pieces.  A human brain can
>   generally easily keep track of about 7 different things, anything more
>   and it gets confused.  You know you're brilliant, but maybe you'd like
>   to understand what you did 2 weeks from now.

So while C99 style in-place initialisers are handy in certain cases the first thing you should probably be asking yourself is why it's hard to have them all at the top of the function. This doesn't prevent you from declaring stuff inside block markers, for example for in-loop calculations.

Answer (score 0):

In older C it is possible to declare them locally by creating a block inside the function. Blocks can be added even without ifs/for/while:

```
int foo(void)
{
    int a;
    int b;

    ....

    a = 5 + b;

    {
         int c;
         ....
    }
}
```

Although it doesn't look very neat, it still is possible, even in older C.

Answer (score -1):

I can't speak to why they have done things one way in the Linux kernel, but in the systems we develop, we tend to not use C99-specific features in the core code.  Individual applications tend to have stuff written for C99, because they will typically be deployed to one known platform, and the gcc C99 implementation is known good.

But the core code has to be deployable on whatever platform the customer demands (within reason).  We have supplied systems on AIX, Solaris, Informix, Linux, Tru-64, OpenVMS(!) and the presence of C99 compliant compilers isn't always guaranteed.

The Linux kernel needs to be substantially more portable again - and particularly down to small footprint embedded systems.  I guess the feature just isn't important enough to override these sorts of considerations.

Comment: No that reasoning doesn't hold for the linux kernel at all. They clearly have gcc as their compiler and use a lot of gcc extensions. So allowing declarations in C99 style wouldn't cost them anything concerning portability.

Comment: Yes, but much (most probably) of the kernel was written before C99 was standardised, and it was another few years before gcc had good, reliable support (although admittedly mixed declarations and code is a 'Done' feature from gcc 3 onwards - mid 2001).  And porting the kernel to the new standard is likely not one of the first things you would do ...  i.e. my reason holds for the time period when the vast majority of kernel code was written, and there isn't a compelling reason to go and rewrite it.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. It's purely a matter of style, not compatibility. Linux (the kernel) is completely plastered with non-portable, gcc-specific pseudo-C code. Depending on C99 is therefore not an additional dependency.

Comment: @asc99c I remove accept from the answer, sorry. But pmg's answer "the target architecture may not have a C99 compiler" thus also incorrect. IMHO the closest is Earn in Zimmerman in comment to its answer

Comment: Yep that's fine, was having a look and agree it is now gcc-specific.  I thought a degree of separation used to exist between the Linux kernel and the GNU ecosystem of software.